# Can't access a property in an API using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve data from an API using jQuery but I am unable to get a response.

This is the API endpoint I am using (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=frank%2525ocean&format=json&gsrprop=snippet&prop=info&inprop=url).

This is the code to retrieve the property 'gsroffset':

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=frank%ocean&format=json&gsrprop=snippet&prop=info&inprop=url", function(x){
    var testCheck = x.continue.gsroffset;
    console.log(testCheck);
  });
});
```

But the value does not appear in my console.

Comment: Do you recieve any errors in the console?

Comment: @S.Walker Nah noting appears

Comment: You can't query wikipedia, because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), You would see it in console: Failed to load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=frank%ocean&format=json&gsrprop=snippet&prop=info&inprop=url: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Interesting thanks. The wiki API is messed up.

Comment: I threw the code in a simple web page and got this error on the Chrome browser console: "Failed to load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=frank%ocean&format=json&gsrprop=snippet&prop=info&inprop=url: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access."   HOWEVER, using Postman, the url did fetch the data; and that header referenced in the error above, was not in the GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "origin" key set equal to value'*' at the end of your url
like this :`"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=frank%ocean&format=json&gsrprop=snippet&prop=info&inprop=url&origin=*"`